# Extracting data column-wise from table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I currently have a piece of code that pivots a table in which the row data is inserted dynamically. The code is shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
     ([empname] varchar(6), [empqual] varchar(10), [emprank] int, [empexp] int)


INSERT INTO Table1
     ([empname], [empqual], [emprank], [empexp])
VALUES
     ('Joyce', 'UNIVERSITY', 1, 11),
     ('Angela', 'MASTERS', 2, 10),
     ('Lily', 'MASTERS', 3, 9),
     ('Sasha', 'UNIVERSITY', 3, 9),
     ('Harry', 'UNIVERSITY', 3, 9)

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + 'Column' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,Row_Number() OVER (Order By emprank))
        FROM Table1 c
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

SET @query = '
 SELECT * 
 FROM 
 (
   SELECT ''Column'' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,Row_Number() OVER (Order By emprank)) AS Columns, 
   CONVERT(VARCHAR,empname) as e 
   FROM Table1 
 ) p
 PIVOT
 (
   MAX (e)
   FOR Columns IN
   ( 
     ' + @cols + ' )
   ) as pvt

 UNION

 SELECT * 
 FROM 
 (
   SELECT ''Column'' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,Row_Number() OVER (Order By emprank)) AS Columns, 
   CONVERT(VARCHAR,empqual) as e 
   FROM Table1 
 ) p
 PIVOT
 (
   MAX (e)
   FOR Columns IN
   ( 
     ' + @cols + ' )
   ) as pvt

 UNION

 SELECT * 
 FROM 
 (
   SELECT ''Column'' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,Row_Number() OVER (Order By emprank)) AS Columns, 
   CONVERT(VARCHAR,emprank) as e 
   FROM Table1 
 ) p
 PIVOT
 (
   MAX (e)
   FOR Columns IN
   ( 
      ' + @cols + ' )
   ) as pvt

 UNION 

 SELECT * 
 FROM 
 (
   SELECT ''Column'' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,Row_Number() OVER (Order By emprank)) AS Columns, 
   CONVERT(VARCHAR,empexp) as e, 
   FROM Table1 
 ) p
 PIVOT
 (
   MAX (e)
   FOR Columns IN
   ( 
      ' + @cols + ' )
   ) as pvt
 '
EXECUTE (@query)
```

The result of the above code is as shown below:

```
  Column1    Column2    Column3    Column4    Column5
     1          2          3          3          3
    11         10          9          9          9
   Joyce      Angela      Lily      Sasha      Harry
 UNIVERSITY   MASTERS    MASTERS  UNIVERSITY  UNIVERSITY
```

Now, my application requires that I display each of the columns in this table separately, i.e. each of the **columns**, and not rows, of this table needs to be exported from this table and transferred, possibly into a temporary table, from which it can be displayed easily.

I am well aware of the fact that relational DBs are designed in such a way so as to consider rows, not columns, as individual entities. However, I am constrained by the application on which I am working, which requires code that extracts the data in this table column-wise so that they can be displayed separately.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: so you're pivoting the data from rows into columns and now you want what was previously in a row, but returned as a column? Why exactly are you pivoting the data instead of just returning a row from the original data?

Comment: I require my data to be displayed in columns, thus the transposing from row-wise to column-wise. Pivoting the data gives me the required format.

Comment: ...I think you're seriously misunderstanding the concept of SQL columns as opposed to display columns.

Comment: It seems like your requirement is from a UI perspective. Just return the data as rows and get your application to handle a row at a time, formatting it as required. Show some application code and desired output if possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is a terminology overlap.

- In SQL, "row" means (roughly) a single entity, and "column" means a property on the entities.
- In UI, "row" means data arranged horizontally, and "column" means data arranged vertically.

Your requirement is that you should display your entities vertically. So, retrieve your entities (SQL *rows*) and then add code in your application to display this data in UI *columns*. It's unfortunate and perhaps confusing that the terms are the same here, but remember, your database structure (and choice of terminology) is completely irrelevant to your UI layout.

As to what code in your application is required to display the data... well, you haven't even told us what language it's in, so I can't help there.

Comment: As I said in the original post, I entirely understand the fact that that, in SQL, the 'row' represents the single entity, and not the column. I have no misunderstanding there. What I do know, is that the front-end of the application (which does not fall under my purview) directly displays the grid as it is coded in SQL. This 'layout', as you term it, cannot be changed by the UI.

Comment: Right. You never specified that. You said your application requires things to be *displayed* in columns; it sounded like you were trying to write the display code. Now... I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for here. If you've got a program that displays columns, then you're done, because that query outputs your data in columns already. What output does your app give when presented with the query in your question?

Comment: Also I know this might not help you, but if you've got a program designed to take input from SQL that's set up to treat *columns* as entities, and not rows, then I suspect that either it's very poorly designed or you're using it for something it's not intended for.